# A inherits from B, B inherits from C. Will initializing A invoke constructor of C?

Tags: java, oop, constructor

As I was preparing for an interview about OOP, I came across this question.

A inherits form B. B inherits from C. 
Will initializing A invoke constructor of C?

What I know is that a constructed is not inherited. We have to use the super keyword to refer to the parent's constructor. Am I right?

Comment: There's always an implicit `super()` call if you don't do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor of a subclass will first invoke the constructor of its super class. If a class has several ancestors, these calls will be stacked until the constructor of the top ancestor is called. Then, it will continue executing the constructor of the next ancestors until all the constructor of the ancestors were executed. You can infer from here that every time you create an object, the constructor of `Object` class is invoked, **always**.

Note that if you don't add the call to `super()` in the subclass constructor, the compiler will add it for you automatically. If there's no default constructor for the super class and you don't specify the call to the specific constructor of the super class in the constructor of the subclass, then you will get a compiler error.

All these rules are stated in [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8).

Comment: @BoristheSpider reworded the first sentence to give a better look on this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

In the world of Java, when you are extending another class, you only see your direct super class' constructor. The super class is supposed to proper encapsulate the super-super class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There will always be an *implicit* call to the constructor of the base class. In your case, the constructor of `C` will be called first, then the constructor of `B` and finally the constructor of `A`.

Using `super` is useful when you have defined overloaded constructors, and you want to call a specific one.